# Can't change button title style in iOS: attributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to update the title of an iOS `UIButton` named cardButton, with the RED word mat.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [card.contents mutableCopy];
NSInteger _stringLength=[mat length];
UIColor *color;
color = [UIColor redColor];
[mat addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
[cardButton setAttributedTitle: mat forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`NSLog` returns the right word for the word mat.
I have the following error. I know there is a problem with memory management, but I don't know what.

```
-[__NSCFString addAttribute:value:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7177370
```

Thanks!

Comment: NSLog the _stringLength?

Comment: What type is `card.contents`? I guess, it is not `NSMutableAttributedString`, and thus, `mat` is neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [card.contents mutableCopy];
```

with this :

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[card.contents mutableCopy]];
```